# How to open file and insert text using the VSCode API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I open a new read-only text file in tab and insert some formatted text in that file using the Visual Studio Code API?

I didnt find any example regarding this to add simple text

Following is my code that opens some untitled file.

```
var setting: vscode.Uri = vscode.Uri.parse("untitled:" + "C:\summary.txt");
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(setting).then((a: vscode.TextDocument) => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(a, 1, false);
}, (error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
    debugger;
});
```

Please give the simple example that can be added to these lines to add the text.
As the official examples are little complex.

Comment: do not use `Uri.parse` for files. Use `Uri.file`. File name/path might contain `#` character

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following should give you the idea

```
...
var setting: vscode.Uri = vscode.Uri.parse("untitled:" + "C:\summary.txt");
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(setting).then((a: vscode.TextDocument) => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(a, 1, false).then(e => {
        e.edit(edit => {
            edit.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), "Your advertisement here");
        });
    });
}, (error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
    debugger;
});
...
```

Comment: So how to insert a text in active document ?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar get editor using  `const e = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;` then you can use `e.edit()` as in DAXaholic's answer

Comment: Is there also a way to add text coming from API?

Answer (score 5):

In adition to DAXaholic's answer, **If you want to insert text to the active editor**, `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` can be used.

```
function enterText(text: string) {
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (editor) {
        editor.edit(editBuilder => {
            editBuilder.insert(editor.selection.active, text);
        });
    }
}
```

In my example text is inserted to the currunt curser position.

Comment: just what I needed, thanks!